# Strapi sum values for a certain field

Tags: strapi

i'm trying to build an api for expenses notes with strapi.
I have trips and for each trip multiple expenses. (relation one to many).
I would like, when I go to /trips it will give me also the sum of all expenses for that trip. (each expense will have the proper amount)
I would need the sumField only in response and not on the model of the api (so i cannot modify it).
I Am using postrgres.
Definetelly i have to modify the controller find and find one but I don't know how make the sum.

Also if it is possible to have it querable from graphql.
Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Exactly you will have to customize your API to add a new route and controller (to keep the current default API stuff) that will return what you need.

First you will have to create a route and a controller in the API you want. Trip in you case.
There is a doc here for an API named hello - replace hello by post. https://strapi.io/documentation/3.0.0-beta.x/guides/controllers.html#custom-controllers

And then in your controller, you will have something like this:

```
const { sanitizeEntity } = require('strapi-utils');

module.exports = {
  async tripsWithSum (ctx) {
    let entities;
    if (ctx.query._q) {
      entities = await strapi.services.trip.search(ctx.query);
    } else {
      entities = await strapi.services.trip.find(ctx.query);
    }

    entities = entities.map(entity => sanitizeEntity(entity, { model: Trip }));

    entities = entities.map(entry => {
      entry = Object.assign(entry, {
        sumField: entry.expenses.length
      });
    });

    return entities;
  }
};
```

Comment: Any tips on how to sort nested fields (expenses) by rest query? do I need to extend moreover the controller or I can use directly strapi to handle this?

Comment: You will have to manipulate your fetched data by customizing the controller.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you I will try. what if expenses is a relation field? Trips will have many expenses.